# Pop up window not appearing

Tags: javascript

My pop up window is not appearing. It is suppose to appear after my validation but even though the validation is working, the pop up window is not appearing. Does anyone have any ideas:

```js
function validation() {
    var isDataValid = true;
    var textO = document.getElementsByName("textBox1");               
    var errMsgO = document.getElementById("txtBox1Alert");

    if (textO.value == '') {
       errMsgO.innerHTML = "Text Box is empty";
       isDataValid = false;
    } else {
       errMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
    }
    if(isDataValid) {
       function openSessionPopup (txt) {
         window.open(txt, 'window', 'width=500,height=500,scrollbars=yes,status=no');
       }  
    }  
}

function myClickHandler(){
    if(validation()){
       showSessionPopup();
    }
}
```

In Html Form:

```html
 <p><input class="questionBtn" type="button" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="myClickHandler()"/></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is working in that code:

- The function "validation" does not return a value;
- You put the function "openSessionPopup" inside another function, you can't do that;
- You call the function "showSessionPopup()" but it's not defined anywhere;

Look at the error console of your browser. It should have given you lots of warnings and errors.